# Error creating a SVN repo

Tags: svn, localhost, git-svn, repository

Ok, I've been learning GIT and SVN past few weeks. Managed to grasp what GIT can do (simply amazing) and got it set up, along with Drush for my Drupal installs to sync my multi-installations. But I just can't figure out how to understand SVN for some of my companies older sites.

On my local machine, I installed xCode with the command line tools to get **svn v1.6.18** install and have a **svn v1.6.12** repo already set up on the web server with ssh access.

On my local machine, I tried creating a new repo and always get the error: `svn: warning: '.' is not a working copy`. Try doing anything I get that. Followed some tutorials and most of them want me to do `svnadmin`. Which isn't even a working command.

Feel like I'm missing something so darn simple (like a `svn init`...?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

subversion works with a central repo <> git which has several repos => you checkout the central repo from your server and once your changes have been implemented, you commit them back to the central repo on the server. There's no 'local pushing' as there is in GIT.

Comment: So one would just use `svn co [url to repo] [local directory/file]`?

Comment: you cd to the location where you checked out the repo on your local machine and there you use svn co [local directory/file]

Comment: Got it. Thanks @Jeroen. If I wanted to commit on the repo on the server. Is it possible to do it straight from the local machine or do you have to ssh into the server?

Comment: @Josh: there are no local commits in SVN; all commits are made to the repo (which usually lives on another machine).

Comment: To be clear, it is possible to have local SVN repositories. You create them using `svnadmin` (assuming you have that installed) and check them out using `file:///` URLs. However, the repo usually has to live separately from the working copy.

Comment: @nneonneo Thanks so much for the info. I've seen the use of `svnadmin` but didn't know you had to install something completely separate.